# Responsive images of srcset attribute are not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, image, responsive-design, responsive

I'm fixing some code in a review web application project. one of the submission criteria is to make all of the site images responsive using `srcset` attribute. But the site is only loading the larger image in all viewports and screen sizes and I don't know where I went wrong!!

Here's the **HTML** portion in with the target `img` tag, which is being built dynamically with the javascript afterward

```
<section id="restaurant-container">
    <h1 id="restaurant-name"></h1>
    <img id="restaurant-img">
    <p id="restaurant-cuisine"></p>
    <p id="restaurant-address"></p>
    <table id="restaurant-hours"></table>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
function imageUrlForRestaurant(restaurant) {
    let url = `/img/${(restaurant.photograph.split('.')[0]||restaurant.id)}-medium.jpg`;
    return url;
  }

function imageSrcsetForRestaurant(restaurant) {
    const imageSrc = `/img/${(restaurant.photograph.split('.')[0]||restaurant.id)}`;
    return `${imageSrc}-small.jpeg 300w,
            ${imageSrc}-medium.jpeg 600w,
            ${imageSrc}-large.jpeg 800w`;
  }

function imageSizesForRestaurant(restaurant) {
    return `(max-width: 360px) 280px,
            (max-width: 600px) 600px,
            400px`;
  }


const image = document.getElementById('restaurant-img');
image.className = 'restaurant-img';
image.src = imageUrlForRestaurant(restaurant);
image.srcset = imageSrcsetForRestaurant(restaurant);
image.sizes = imageSizesForRestaurant(restaurant);
```

Comment: What're the actual sizes of the images, as in on your computer? Also the function for `imageSizesForRestaurant`, the last value is `400px`, not `800px` as it should be

Comment: large: 800x600
medium: 600x450
small: 300x225

why does it matter? isn't 400px just the slot size the image is going to take based on screen width?

Comment: Instead of all these JS functions, have you tried to write out the HTML simplified? Meaning, have the HTML be this: ```<img src="/img/someSmallImage.jpg"
     srcset="/img/someSmallImage.jpg 300w,
            /img/someMediumImage.jpg 600w,
      /img/someLargeImage.jpg 800w"
  sizes="(max-width: 300px) 300px,
         (max-width: 600px) 600px,
   800px"/>```

Comment: Srcset is smart enough to look at device pixel ratio, not just viewport width. It's possible your problem is simply that all your images are real small. Even a 320px-wide iPhone SE, when you take into account a DPI of 2, will want an image that's 640px wide, which is wider than your small and medium ones, so it'd go for the 800px image. Try adding an image into your srcset that's like 2000px wide and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Well, I haven't. because it's a template for many pages of different restaurants and each has its own images and therefore needs to be built dynamically on demand.
what do you suggest

Comment: @cjl750 yeah. good point. maybe I'll give it a try.
However I used <picture> and <source> tags instead and it works